# ngFor generated input fields get different values - Angular 2

Tags: angular, input, binding, ngmodel

I have two (or perhaps more) input fields that are generated when I click on button. Currently, when I start to type something in any filed, it will also fill in other fields with that ngModel.

What i need is to make every row for it self so that when i click other button, it will get all input values and push them in array by rows so json should look something like this:

```
[{"name":"aaa", "data":"111"},{"name":"bbb", "data":"222"},{"name":"ccc", "data":"333"}]
```

Plunker is here: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mg53gD2GyJhb4EzeAIza?p=preview)

Comment: There is no JSON in your question...

Comment: Anyway, your pushing a reference to an existing object into the array. Try `this.properties.push({...this.property})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you need is something like the following.

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
        <div *ngFor="let prop of properties; let i=index">
            <input type="text" placeholder="name" [(ngModel)]="prop.name"/>
            <input type="text" placeholder="data" [(ngModel)]="prop.data"/>
        </div>
    <button (click)="createRow()">Add row inputs</button>
    <button (click)="addRow()">show array input rows</button>
`,
})
export class App {
    // property = { name:"", data: "" };
    properties = [];

    createRow(){
        this.properties.push({ name:"", data: "" });
    }

    addRow() {
        console.log(this.properties);
    }
}
```

The plunk didn't have a whole lot in it, so I don't know where you plan to go with this.

Adding `let i=index` after the let part of the `*ngFor` gets you the index for the current item in the array. You can use that in your `[(ngModel)]` to tell Angular what to bind to from one row to the next.

Comment: Yes, that is exaclty what I need ...I added function on second button: https://plnkr.co/edit/DSai2pfceIIBUxfSty0g?p=preview
...but for some reason, with your correction, I still don't catch values in array when it is showing in console.log

Comment: A small note: the template would be simpler with this syntax: `[(ngModel)]="prop.name"`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Indeed it would! Updated answer. Thanks.